# Low-noise SPDT switch

Tags: switches, adc, noise

I need to produce an extremely low noise SPDT switch. This switch will take two different inputs to a single 16 bit ADC. The inputs are 50 ohm BNC outputs from trans-impedance amplifiers. The amplifiers take a small current and convert them to 0-10V DC (they operate between 200 KHz and several MHz). This signal is then sampled at a rate of 1 MHz to 80 MHz, depending on application.

Currently I use the following component:

http://www.jfwindustries.com/products/50S_1313_12_SMA_Electro_mechanical_Switch_from_JFW_Industries-368-76.html

I tried to design a simple PCB using an OMRON relay. However, this introduced significant baseline voltage as well as noise (100-250 mV plus noise).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to design such a circuit? I tried some off-the-shelf RF switch ICs demo boards but nothing handles DC and/or they clipped at VCC = 3.3V and I need transmission to the full 10V range.

Is there something special about getting a board built at 50 Ohm controlled impedance? I used a single IC to power the relay and a 7805 regulator to provide 5V (the ground is shared with the SMA connectors and power supply).

[image]

[image]

Comment: why not use a load switch ic? super quick google search yielded this: http://www.ti.com/product/tps27082l. Also, please post a schematic; a sch will help in getting quicker more relevant answer

Comment: Try [mini-circuits.](http://www.minicircuits.com/products/switches_coax_1.shtml)

Comment: Analogue switches sound suitable.

Comment: DG series analog switch family should work for you.

Comment: I added the schematics and layout. Also I realized that on this version the ground is shared with the 5V wall power supply.

Comment: Re: mini circuits labs, all their switches state "All RF connections must be DC blocked or held at 0V DC." My concern is that my signal isn't really RF, it just happens to be changing very quickly and randomly. This confounds "RF switches" as best I can tell.